# Question about running a function with parameters in javascript in WkWebView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

```
.
.
.

<script>
    function resizeFont(font_index) {
         var arrFontSize = ["80%", "90%", "100%", "110%", "120%"];
         var x = document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN");
         for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
             x[i].style.fontSize = arrFontSize[font_index];
         }
    }
</script>
```

The above function is to adjust the font of the page that shows the contents of the book.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let contentController = WKUserContentController()

        contentController.add(self, name: "resizeFont")

        webConfiguration.userContentController = contentController
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.containerView.frame, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(ebView)
    }


extension SearchWVViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {

        if let name = message.name as? String, name == "resizeFont" {

            //code
        }
}
```

The code above executes a function with no parameters to pass. But how do I execute a function while passing a `font_index`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute JS function for WKWebView just use `evaluateJavaScript` method e.g.

```
let fontIndex = 1
webView.evaluateJavaScript("resizeFont(\(fontIndex))")
```

Use `userContentController(:)` if you want to receive messages from JS running in a webpage. But in your case, if you want to just execute some JS function in a webpage, you don't need to use `WKUserContentController` and `WKScriptMessageHandler`, just use `evaluateJavaScript` method.